# Can a self-similar shape not be a polytope yet have a non-fractal boundary?

Tags: fractals, polytopes, iterated-function-system

Looking at the Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rep-tile all examples of rep-tiles that are not polygons have fractal boundaries.

In general, if the Hutchinson attractor of an IFS of similitudes is not a polytope (or apeirotrope), is it's boundary fractal?

Comment: Which definition of "Fractal" are you thinking of?

Comment: @YuvalPeres Of non-integer Haussdorf dimension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The four corner set $K$ (which is a Cartesian square of the middle half Cantor set) has an empty interior (so it coincides with its boundary) and has Hausdorff dimension 1. The set $K$ is  self-similar, as it is a union of four images $f_i(K)$ by contracting similarity maps.

Comment: Are there any examples which do not coincide with their boundaries?

Comment: I can't think of such an example yet. You may find this paper interesting: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864198000315